# Make div transparent through parent div

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a div on top of an image and inside that div to have a border or another div that is transparent so you can see the image below.

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.floater {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.title,
.description {
  padding: 10px
}

.transparent-through {
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="floater">
    <div class="title">
      My Title
    </div>
    <div class="transparent-through"></div>
    <div class="description">
      Short Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the back "transparent-through" div transparent so you can see the image underneath the parent div.

and example is here:
[image]

Comment: If the blue section is opaque, you can't make use of a secondary `<div>` to 'cut out' a piece of that opaqueness and make it transparent. You would need to create an element(s) that simply make up the shape in question. That would likely either require four separate `<div>` elements, or one `<svg>`.

Comment: No need for Fiddles. Just put your code in a "code snippet", right here in your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiple background using `linear-gradient` to create the transparent part without the need of an extra element:

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
}

.floater {
  width: 400px;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 0/100% 50px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 100%/100% 50px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 0 0/50px 100% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(blue,blue) 100% 0/50px 100% no-repeat;
 
}

.title,
.description {
  padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="floater">
    <div class="title">
      My Title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Short Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a more ticky idea using `clip-path`:

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
}

.floater {
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 20% 100%, 20% 29%, 75% 29%, 75% 69%, 20% 69%, 20% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 20% 100%, 20% 29%, 75% 29%, 75% 69%, 20% 69%, 20% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  background:blue;
}

.title,
.description {
  padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="floater">
    <div class="title">
      My Title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Short Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another one using inset box-shadow:

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
}

.floater {
  width: 400px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 50px blue inset;
}

.title,
.description {
  padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="floater">
    <div class="title">
      My Title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Short Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also consider pseudo-element with borders:

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
}

.floater {
  position:relative;
  width: 400px;
  z-index:0;
}
.floater:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-width:50px 20px 50px 20px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:blue;
  z-index:-1;
}

.title,
.description {
  padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="floater">
    <div class="title">
      My Title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Short Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: clip-path would be the answer 'd pick up

Comment: Which one would you recommend if the ".floater" needs to be responsive, and the title and description might be 1 line, 2 lines or 3 lines of text?

Comment: @nad90 it will depend on the responsiveness ... I would consider the first two method where we can speficify percentage values And all depend on how you will deal with the hole when description will grow, it will fixed, it will grow, etc ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif keeping the "transparent-through" div, how can I add a liniar-gradient or background image to the "floater" div? I tried with the box-shadow but it looks like I can only assign a color and not a liniar gradient or image to it

Answer (score 2):

A trik could be to draw the background-color from a shadow from your border element.*(see css comments)*

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
}

.floater {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden; /*keep children shadow inside*/
  margin: auto
}

.title,
.description {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative; /* on top of sibblings shadows*/
}

.transparent-through {
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px blue; /* tune color and area to fill unblured. here set to blue and 100px around */
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="floater">
    <div class="title">
      My Title
    </div>
    <div class="transparent-through"></div>
    <div class="description">
      Short Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems @vals was faster than you for this one :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif did not saw his answer untill now ;) ... was looking for old example on codepen and i dislike the way how you can hardly search only your own pens  .... (maybe time to look for another online code editor)  ... i finally found one example ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nKAka and gave up to look for others

Comment: yes I know, I was joking ;) ... at least you didn't pick my gradient idea, I know you are fan of them :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif i thought about it, but  text size or length could vary ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr can I use a liniar gradient as a color for the box-shadow? I would need this background in the "floater" div:   background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #4816af 12.50%, #5400ff 12.50%, #5400ff 50%, #4816af 50%, #4816af 62.50%, #5400ff 62.50%, #5400ff 100%)
 background-size: 11.31px 11.31px

Comment: @nad90 not too sure i understand what you try to do. what you can is add as many shadows you want to mimic somehow a gradient, but you cannot use a gradient to set a shadow color :( For this specific look, shadows will not be able to draw it)

Comment: @G-Cyr I ended up using an svg... the problem was the background with the stripped lines. I use a linear gradient for it which is not supported in the box-shadow. I tried with clip-path but the svg is much better for this case. The only problem is that it's not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Create the blue background as a shadow of the transparent-through element.

Set overflow hidden on the floater to keep it from expanding outwards

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
}

.floater {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title,
.description {
  padding: 10px
}

.transparent-through {
  height: 60px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="floater">
    <div class="title">
      My Title
    </div>
    <div class="transparent-through"></div>
    <div class="description">
      Short Description
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we can also consider inset box-shadow on the main container and avoid the extra element

Comment: @TemaniAfif inset shadow requires fixed size so the shadows stops where expected, outside shadow is the most fluid and shortest way to manage this ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr we can still use multiple inset shadow and control the sizing https://jsfiddle.net/45592hz0/1/ ;)

Answer (score -1):

make the parent div position:relative and z-index:0 and make the child div position:absolute and z-index:10

this is an example follow this example you can do it .

```css
.check
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:50%:
z-index:0;
}
.check img
{
width:100%;
height:50%;
}
.form-box
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    z-index:10;
    height:100%;
    padding-top:40px;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="check">
<img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/th5YNVqlkHqkz03Va5RPOXZQRhA=/0x0:2040x1360/1200x800/filters:focal(857x517:1183x843)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/57358643/jbareham_170504_1691_0020.0.0.jpg">
</div>
<div class="form-box">
<h1>BISWAJIT</h1>
</div>
```