# See parent's parent's color in child via transparency technique

Tags: html, css

This is a pretty weird request, but I was wondering if it was possible. I've been staring at this for a while, and wasn't even sure how to explain it for the longest time.

I need the child div's background to be the parent div's parent background.

```css
.body {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lavender;
}

.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="body center">
  <div class="parent center">
    <div class="child center" />
  </div>
</div>
```

If you run the code and look at the visual, you will see that the structure is like this:

Body == Lavender

Parent == Pink

Child == Blue

This might not be possible, but what I am trying to accomplish is "see-through" the Parent while in the Child in order to get the Child's background to be the  lavender color of the Body. Ideally I would have a transparent background on the Child and the Parent would somehow enable this pass through of transparency..

Comment: This is not achievable with the current state of development of css. Although, you can achieve it by "cheating". You can declare the same background color to `.child` and it will look like it's passing through. 

If you're asking how to achieve this with images though, there might be a slightly different way.

Comment: Yeah @Adriano I think you might be right about it being impossible... I've spent a decent amount of time with CSS over the past few years, but this really has me completely stumped. However, sometimes people on the internet surprise me with their workarounds, maybe someone will find a way.

Comment: @temani afif is a CSS hacker, he had made me wonder many times with his solutions. maybe he could help

Comment: @JoykalInfotech thanks for the info, I'll see if I can contact him.

Comment: What are you trying to use this for? Depending on the situation, the parent may not need to be one element. You could split it into 4 separate elements, making an actual hole in the middle. Or, you could use JavaScript to clone the contents/background of body to the child and position it so they line up correctly even as you scroll.

Comment: you can apply a background to the `parent` such that it excludes the `child` ? see https://jsfiddle.net/7ojzusxy/

Comment: @kukkuz Hey, wow.

Comment: is it only a visual effect or you aim to do something more complex? depending on what you want there is solutions (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49967847/8620333 .. I have more, will try to find them)

Comment: another related one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50242118/8620333

Comment: Wow, @TemaniAfif that box-shadow trick is so cool!!! Thank you for sharing, that is so clever I love it. Basically the product I'm trying to build is like the "pull tab" effect (https://cdn.instructables.com/FOY/OB51/GLK0QHY1/FOYOB51GLK0QHY1.LARGE.jpg) where elements of the foreground assume the parent's parent background so that a sweeping left to right change of that background would be visible across all child components.

Comment: you have also the `background-attachment:fixed` trick like this too: https://jsfiddle.net/7bagrphj/ (I have a question about but not able to find it)